# Error using mongoose: TypeError: Invalid schema configuration: `Model` is not a valid type at path

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

My Role.js looks like this:

```
const mongoose = require ("mongoose");

const roleSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    role : Number,
    description : String            
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Role", roleSchema);
```

In my logic.js, I am trying to do this:

```
const Role = require('./Collections/Role');
const role = Role.create({
        role: 2,
        description: 'Editor'
    })    
    console.log(role);
```

I can't seem to get it right. I found a couple other threads with almost similar problem, but it didn't help me.

I also tried

```
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const roleSchema = new Schema({ ...
...
const Role = mongoose.model("Role", roleSchema);
module.exports = Role;
```

The error

```
C:\Users\my_is\Programming\Project\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema.js:1340
    throw new TypeError(`Invalid schema configuration: \`${name}\` is not ` +
    ^    
TypeError: Invalid schema configuration: `Model` is not a valid type at path `role`. See 
    at Schema.interpretAsType 
    at Schema.path 
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\my\Programming\Project\Collections\Admin.js:6:30)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1213:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1037:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12)
```

------------------ My Admin.js --------------

```
const mongoose = require ("mongoose");
const Role = require("./Role");
//const Role = require("./Role").schema;  

const adminSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    firstName : String,    
    lasteName : String,
    email : String,
    dateCreate : { type: Date, default : Date.now } ,
    role : Role
})

module.exports = mongoose.model("Admin", adminSchema);
```

Comment: The error is in your `Admin.js` file, please include it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed you include the entire `Role` model in the `adminSchema` rather than just the schema. to fix this change the line `role: Role` into `type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId` and set the reference to the role. here is a example

```
const adminSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    firstName : String,    
    lasteName : String,
    email : String,
    dateCreate : { type: Date, default : Date.now },
    role : { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Role" }
})
```

hope this will work :)

Answer (score -1):

you should export roleSchema from role.js to admin.js
and set role type in admin.js

> **roleSchema**

and it will work...

Comment: How do I do that? I thought that by doing: ```module.exports = mongoose.model("Role", roleSchema);``` I am exporting Role type, and by doing: ```const Role = require("./Role");``` I am importing it?

Comment: No No You should set role type equal roleSchema in adminSchema